# Flask-mongoengine document id

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to implement flask-login in my application which uses flask-mongoengine too. Here is my user proto:

```
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    username = db.StringField(max_length=80)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(db.Document, self).__init__(self)
        try:
            self.username = kwargs['username']
            self.email = kwargs['email']
            self.password = kwargs['password']
        except:
            flash('Bad arguments for User')

    @staticmethod
    def salt_password(password):
        return generate_password_hash(password)

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self._id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.username)

    def check_pwd(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

However, when I call the `login_user(user)` function from my login view, it calls the `get_id` method of the `User`, but `self._id` returns `None`. I also tried `self.id` with the same result. Then, I tried to add the `_id` field explicitely :

```
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField(default=bson.ObjectId())
```

but then, `self._id` gives me `'User u'username'>` instead of the user id.

Any idea of how to retrieve the `_id` of a user ?

Comment: thanks, but no, there is no attribute user_id :( However, I found a workaround using pymongo i.e. user._get_collection() and the find_one query. I'll post it...

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this issue. My User prototype is updated as follow, using pymongo :

```
def get_id(self):
    user_queried = self._get_collection().find_one({'username':self.username, 'email':self.email, 'password':self.password})
    if user_queried is not None:
        return unicode(user_queried['_id'])
    else:
        return 'None'
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't know if an answer to your problem is still needed - you found a solution for you and your question is old. But if someone else comes around i solved it with the following code:

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, FloatField, BooleanField

class User(Document):

name = StringField(primary_key=True, required=True, max_length=50)
mail = StringField(required=True, max_length=255)
password = StringField(required=True, max_length=80)
first_name = StringField(max_length=255)
second_name = StringField(max_length=255)
authenticated = True  # BooleanField(required=True, default=True)
is_active = True  # BooleanField(required=True, default=True)

meta = {'db_alias': 'users'}

@property
def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

@property
def is_active(self):
    return True

@property
def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

def get_id(self):
    return self.name
```

and added the following user_loader

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user = User.objects(name=user_id)[0]
    return user
```